# Spring Boot GS: ComponentScan and ClassNotFoundException for ConnectionFactory

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I'm playing sur the Spring Boot getting started guide but the auto configuration fails and I get:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
```

It seems it's due to the location of the Application class. Where should it be located? At the top-level package (src/main/java) or in a specific package?

Comment: Have you verified all the dependencies?

Answer (score 78):

Your `Application` class should be placed in a specific package and not in the default (top-level) package. For example, put it in `com.example` and place all your application code in this package or in sub-packages like `com.example.foo` and `com.example.bar`.

Placing your `Application` class in the default package, i.e. directly in `src/main/java` isn't a good idea and it will almost certainly cause your application to fail to start. If you do so, you should see this warning:

```
** WARNING ** : Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a @ComponentScan of the default package.
```

Comment: Your answer solves the problem but it would be good to know why this "isn't a good idea" as to me it should not matter where the Application class is.

Comment: Component scanning looks in the package where your main application class is and all of its sub-packages. If you place it in the default package, every single package on the classpath is scanned. At best, that will be a waste of time. At worst it will cause your application to fail to start as it finds components that it should not have found

Comment: Waste of time and finding too much would still be a better case than [ClassNotFoundException] which seems it didn't find anything. Even more so I went over Spring document on where to put the Application class and it literally says  "We recommend that you locate your main application class in a root package" (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html). Am I missing something or is this intentionally misleading?

Comment: Of course it isn't intentionally misleading. That should be clear if you read section 14.1 of the documentation that you have linked to

Answer (score 5):

Do not put the bootup Application Class in default package. This will solve the problem.

Working code:

```
package com.spring.boot.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);         

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the main class to be inside a package. Because Spring boot annotation @SpringBootApplication will look for a package to scan while launching the app.

So make sure there is a package statement on top of your main class file. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I had got the same Problem, 
Soon I realized that I hadn't included my MAIN method in package.
After including main inside the package , spring boot performed without glitches.

Sample program (Basic) -

```
package springbootquickstart;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication

public class application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SpringApplication.run(application.class, args);

    }

}
```

Comment: You can format your code better by adding four spaces before each line.

Comment: @ailnlv, Thank you,, T-Heron did it, Will keep this in mind in future

Answer (score -1):

Your configuration should looks like this and the Application.java should be at the root of you packages E.g /src/main/java/io/eddumelendez

io.eddumelendez is my package

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
  </parent>
  <groupId>io.eddumelendez.jms</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-jms-sample</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>qa</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```